# How to configure nginx listen to port 80 and redirect to my website running on port 80?

Tags: docker, nginx

I want my nginx listen to port 80 and redirect to my website in Tomcat Docker on port 80 as well.

I tried change port of Tomcat to other and when user visits my website, it shows the port number in URL bar. So I want to use the default port 80.

The problem is that I cannot run nginx and Tomcat Docker on port 80 at the same time.

Comment: A redirect always shows the redirected URL. If you don't want this, you must not redirect, but run nginx as a frontend to your tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you should run

-- nginx in port 80

-- set Tomcat to run with another port (e.g. 8080)

-- use proxy_pass option in nginx, setting http://localhost:8080